# Impala Query(dbplyr) Error : Encountered Identifier : expected: (

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, impala, dbplyr

I'm currently working on an impala db and I'm having some problems with dbplyr's SQL translation.

This is the first iteration of my code which works in R if I collect the table beforehand (which is not something I want to do as it takes forever):

```
DF2_V1 <- DF1 %>%
  filter(indicator != "N") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(!("Y" %in% indicator) | (indicator == "Y"),
         !("ANALYSIS" %in% indicator) | (indicator != "RECOMMENDED")) %>%
  filter(time1 == min(time1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(time_diff = time1 - time2) %>%
  select(id,indicator,time1,time2,time_diff %>% show_query() %>% collect()
```

Essentially the goal of this code is to take DF1 ;

| ID | INDICATOR | TIME1 | TIME2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Y | ... | ..... |
| 1 | N | ... | ..... |
| 1 | RECOMMEND | ... | ..... |
| 2 | RECOMMEND | ... | ..... |
| 2 | ANALYSIS | ... | ..... |

And perform the following logic: If a given id has any Y indicator remove the others and keep the earliest iteration of that indicator. If Y is not present, we favor the indicator ANALYSIS instead and take the first iteration (earliest time), if not we take RECOMMENDED. This code works fine in R (when collecting DF1 beforehand) and does what I want *however* when the DF1 table is uncollected and we're performing a SQL query I get the following error:

> Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement, immediate) :
> nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1412: 00000: [RStudio][ImpalaODBC] (360)
> Syntax error occurred during query execution: [HY000] :
> AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 32:
>
> WHEN ('Y' IN indicator) THEN 'Y'
> ^
> Encountered: IDENTIFIER
> Expected: (
>
> CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

I'm still quite new to db queries and I was not sure what to make of this so I tried rewriting the code in R using SQL script in dbplyr which made some minor modifications hoping to clarify my logic:

```
DF2_V2 <- DF1 %>%
  filter(indicator != "NULL") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(indicator = case_when(
    sql("'Y' IN indicator") ~ "Y",
    sql("('ANALYSIS' IN indicator) AND (indicator != 'RECOMMENDED')") ~ "ANALYSIS",
    TRUE ~ "RECOMMENDED")) %>%
  filter(time1 == min(time1)) %>%
  mutate(time_diff = time1 - time2) %>% select(...) %>% collect()
```

This presented with the same error. I also tried my queries directly in the db using the show_query translation to see if it was a problem with R's connection but inevitably came to the same conclusion. Not sure if my code itself is faulty or the translation into SQL is being messed up but I cant seem to find the problem.

Comment: I don't use impala, but I've not seen a database where the `IN` infix operator accepts the RHS without surrounding parens. That is, I would expect the raw SQL to need to be `WHEN ('Y' IN (indicator))`, though I'd likely need to see the whole query to know if that itself is the correct logic for what you need. This _might_ be a bug in `dbplyr`, not sure.

Comment: Okay so you're right the problem was the parens, I modified and ran the code in the db and it ran. For some reason dbplyr isn't naturally surrounding any of those colnames with parentheses when using R's %in% which I find it rlly strange considering how often I've used it in the past. Nevertheless modifying the second iteration of my code and explicitly putting parens has done the trick. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's a bug in `dbplyr`, but forcing the parens should work:

```r
DF2_V1 <- DF1 %>%
  filter(indicator != "N") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(!("Y" %in% (indicator)) | (indicator == "Y"),
         !("ANALYSIS" %in% (indicator)) | (indicator != "RECOMMENDED")) %>%
  filter(time1 == min(time1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(time_diff = time1 - time2) %>%
  select(id,indicator,time1,time2,time_diff %>% show_query() %>% collect()
```

(This might be specific to the impala backend/driver, not sure.)